# Very old doc-file with equations

Tags: microsoft-word, documents, equation-editor

I have certain doc files, made in 1999, possibly on already old software. These doc files have had equations or other mathematical expressions in them.

If I open these files with notepad, I can see "Equation" on certain places, which leads me to believe that the information is still there, but when I open it with OpenOffice, in these same places, I only see: "µ §".

The docs in question can be downloaded from here: https://ortvay.elte.hu/regi/regi.html

Please help me with reconstructing the equations as they were. I tried to convert the doc into odt, but it could not do it without error message.

Comment: Documents in Hungarian? Is Hungarian installed on your computer? I don't have Hungarian, but LibreOffice Writer opens up something that you can already work with (encodings, languages).  https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/243764/problem-with-changing-document-language/

Comment: Language is not a problem. The only problem is that mathematical formulas are not displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old documents contain a wealth of formula characters. There is a risk that your very old documents will no longer be readable.

But, your further steps depend on some boundary conditions too you didn't describe in your question:

- Be able to read formulas only.
- Make formulas available editable in new documents.
- Microsoft Word is available
- former Microsoft Word 2000 is available at a friend's place
- commercial software e.g. MathType should be avoided (see link below).

OpenOffice is not the right way from my point of view. You need an old version of Microsoft Word - *before Microsoft Equation Editor was dropped* - to read the files. On an old laptop running Windows 7 with Word 2000 I was able to open and read the files and formulas (see screenshot). However, the recovery is overlaid with characters. But here I have then language difficulties with Hungarian to understand the formulas.

[image]

**Further information:**

Equation Editor was a formula editor developed by Design Science that allowed users to construct math and science equations in a WYSIWYG environment, and was included in Microsoft Office and several other commercial applications. It was a simplified version of Design Science's MathType, evidenced with a dialog box enticing the user to upgrade to the full, paid version of the software. It could be used as a standalone program or as an embedded object from within applications that support OLE. Its feature set had not changed significantly since its introduction in Word for Windows version 2.0.

Beginning with Office 2007, Equation Editor is no longer the default method of creating equations, and is kept for compatibility with old documents only. Instead, a reengineered equation editor is included, which is built into the document-editing part of the Fluent User Interface on core Office 2007 programs and all Office 2010 and 2013 programs, rather than accessed through a separate dialog and being treated as an OLE object in the document. In January 2018, Microsoft published a security update that completely removed the old Equation Editor for Office 2007, Office 2010, Office 2013 and Office 2016 when the update was installed, due to a vulnerability that was being actively exploited.

Quoted from [Microsoft Office support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/equation-editor-6eac7d71-3c74-437b-80d3-c7dea24fdf3f):

> However, users can edit these equations only by downloading the MathType software tools that are provided by WIRIS. [See MathType desktop for Equation Editor users.](http://www.wiris.com/en/equation_editor/microsoft)

Please read the following information but be careful with the described steps on your PC (I never tried).

The whole terrible story with the formula editor security fixes and the man's way is described in [Reactivate Microsoft Office Equation Editor 3.0](https://borncity.com/win/2020/02/02/reactivate-microsoft-office-equation-editor-3-0/).

Comment: Thank you very much, with your help I could open the files perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

LibreOffice may be an option as a contingency plan.
I had a 2008 .doc file with equations, the current MS Word cannot display the equations, which appear as empty boxes. LibreOffice (7.4) displays the equation correctly as images. At least I could see the equations and did not have to derive them again, but I had to re-type them, no way to copy-paste them in a usable form.